# Using Voce speech recognition in Java

Tags: java, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I've been trying to get speech recognition to work on a Java application, I've tried Sphinx but it's too complex for what I need, so I found Voce.
I'm trying to get the recognition demo to work.
The problem is I can't initialize the SpeechInterface, here's the code I've been using:

```
voce.SpeechInterface.init("C:/Users/G/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VoceTest/lib",
            false,
            true,
            "C:/Users/G/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VoceTest/lib/gram",
            "digits");
```

I have a grammar file named digits.gram in the gram folder inside the lib folder.
As a result I get:

```
[Voce ERROR] Cannot configure speech recognizer: 
Property Exception component:'jsgfGrammar' property:'grammarLocation' - value        (C:/Users/G/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VoceTest/lib/gram) is not a valid Resource
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ValidatingPropertySheet.setRaw(ValidatingPropertySheet.java:137)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.setProperty(ConfigurationManager.java:250)
at voce.SpeechRecognizer.<init>(SpeechRecognizer.java:85)
at voce.SpeechInterface.init(SpeechInterface.java:79)
at vocetest.VoceTest.main(VoceTest.java:18)
```

I read the [docs](http://voce.sourceforge.net/api/java/classvoce_1_1_speech_interface.html) but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I think that the problem is your path. Why the the `...` in your path?

Comment: That's just simplified for the post, in the real code I have the full path to the project folder. I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"file:/C:/Users/G/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VoceTest/lib/gram","digits");"
```

The above line should work without errors.